# Evaluation of Dirac Delta in Maple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computational-mathematics, dirac-delta

I am going to solve ODE by Differential Transform method by using the code in Maple

`F(0):=0; F(1)=-0.2;`

`for K from 0 to 4 do F(k+2)=1/(k+1)(k+2)(F(k+1)+Dirac(k-4)+3*Dirac(k-0) end do`

it gives the output

```
`F(2)=-1+3/2 Dirac(0)
```

F(3)=-0.067+1/4 Dirac(0)`

what I can do to get the value of `Dirac(0)`

Comment: Type >?Dirac or >??Dirac

Comment: I think computational science SE would be better for this.

Comment: #hamam_Abdullah tried it several time but could not succeed

Comment: @ziauddin Maybe you need load some library or package.

Comment: I am confused; Dirac delta at $0$ is infinity. Surely it is that I do not understand what you are trying to do. I agree with K.defaoite, computational science SE looks a far better place for this question.

Comment: 'Dirac(k-n)=0'        if k=n and Dirac(k-n)=1 otherwise

Comment: That would be the opposite of what is usually understood as discrete Dirac pulse. From your code it looks like `Dirac` is undefined, Maple does not treat this as error but as an implicitly defined function or sequence variable.